# Which browsers support flac audio files?

Tags: audio

I can play them in Chrome, FF and Edge but I'm concerned there may be some browsers that they may not work in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=flac) suggests that it is not supported in Internet Explorer, Opera Mini, or KaiOS Browser. All other current browser versions show they are compatible.